# "An expression of type void cannot be tested for truthiness" occurring when attaching hide function in ngx-bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-bootstrap

To hide the calendar in `ngx-bootstrap` (bsDaterangepicker)
I have wrote this code
I'm simply using the `hide()` function on a scroll event

```
<div class="si-app-pane-body si-app-filter-body-media"  (scroll)="dp.hide() || dp1.hide()"> //line 23

<input type="text" bsDaterangepicker #dp="bsDaterangepicker" >
<input type="text" bsDaterangepicker   #dp1="bsDaterangepicker"  >
```

So now when I scroll , the calendar is going off and all of this is working fine but in the console where I build my project , `ng build --prod --watch`
it is giving this error

> ERROR in
> src/app/Components_And_Modules/riad-ui/Components/filter/filter.component.html(23,9):
> Directive ɵc, Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.
> src/app/Components_And_Modules/riad-ui/Components/filter/filter.component.html(23,75):
> An expression of type 'void' cannot be tested for truthiness

[stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-datepicker-l5pnlv?file=app/app.component.html)

Comment: What are `dp` and `dp1`? Can you please format the HTML such that the individual properties are on a single line so it is easier to read? I suspect that `dp.hide()` and `dp1.hide()` are void-returning functions, so `dp.hide() || dp1.hide()` is not a valid statement (as the error says, "An expression of type 'void' cannot be tested for truthiness")

Comment: @j1mbl3s i have edited to make it short, They are void returning functions i guess. how else do i acheive what i want to then?

Comment: Is it that you want both `dp.hide()` and `dp1.hide()` to run on scroll? Could you replace what you have for `(scroll)=...` with `(scroll)="dp.hide(); dp1.hide();"` or use a function to do that?

Comment: Yes i want that. I will try what you suggested, 
https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker#hide-on-scroll
can you take a look at this?

Comment: `(scroll)="dp.hide();dp1.hide()"` also is giving the same error. :((